# I made a firefox extension, but I have to click the extension icon on the toolbar to make it run. How do I run it automatically when entering da site?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

It's a very simple extension that I've made mostly using ChatGPT's help. Also I am a complete noob in JavaScript so don't except me to know anything about the codes.

I was trying to run the extension automatically, but I have to click the icon on the toolbar to activate it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.